# Adapting Python function easyCrypto() to use a dictionary instead of a multiway if function

Tags: python, dictionary-comprehension

There is an exercise that I was able to complete where I was tasked with implementing a function **easyCrypto()** which took a string for input and returned its encryption as follows:
Every character at an odd position *i* in the alphabet was encrypted with the character at position *i + 1*, and every character at an even position in the alphabet was encrypted with the character at position *i - 1*. ('a' becomes 'b', 'b' becomes 'a', 'c' becomes 'd', etc.) Lowercase remained lowercase and uppercase remained uppercase. This is what I wrote:

```
 from string import ascii_letters
 def easyCrypto(string):
   
    encrypted = ''
    
    for char in string:
        
        if char in ascii_letters:
            ascii_code = ord(char)
            
            if ascii_code % 2 == 1:
               encrypted += chr(ascii_code + 1)
            else:
               encrypted += chr(ascii_code - 1)
                
        else:
            encrypted += char
    print(encrypted)

>>> easyCrypto('abc')
bad
>>> easyCrypto('ZOO')
YPP
```

There is a follow-up exercise that instructs me to redo this problem using a dictionary instead of a multiway if statement. I have not succeeded in various attempts, although I have been fairly close at times. I would like to learn where I am going wrong. Here is the last bit I came up with:

```
from itertools import chain
def easyCrypto(string):
    asciiDict = dict()
    asciiNum = chain(range(65,91), range(97,123))
    for i in asciiNum:
        asciiDict[str(i)] = chr(i)
        for j in range(0, len(string)):
            encrypted = ''
            for string[j] in asciiDict.keys():
                val = asciiDict[string[j]]
                while val % 2 == 1:
                    encrypted += asciiDict[string[j]+1]
                else:
                    encrypted += asciiDict[string[j]-1]
            return encrypted
```

Answer (score 1):

```
t = {i: i-(-1)**i
     for a in [65, 97]
     for i in range(a, a+26)}

def easyCrypto(string):
    print(string.translate(t))

easyCrypto('abc')
easyCrypto('ZOO')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to build the dictionary first, after that loop over the string

```
from itertools import chain
def easyCrypto(string):
    asciiDict = dict()
    asciiNum = chain(range(65,91), range(97,123))
    for i in asciiNum:
        asciiDict[i] = chr(i)
    encrypted = ''
    for cha in string:
        val = ord(cha)
        if val % 2 == 1:
            encrypted += asciiDict[val+1]
        else:
            encrypted += asciiDict[val-1]
    return encrypted
```

Comment: I see...thank you...I was becoming a master of my own faults. ***print(encrypted)